# Meaning of MIPS flags in elf header

Tags: qemu, elf, mips

I was looking at the header of some elf files and noticed something odd:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, big endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  ...
  Flags:                             0x80000027, noreorder, pic, cpic, abi2, mips64r2
  ...
```

Why is it labeled as ELF32 but have a mips64r2 flag? What does that indicate?  Does it mean that the file was compiled as a 32 bit program intended to be run on a 64 bit processor?

Also, if it is running on mips64r2, why is the machine labeled as MIPS r3000?

If I wanted to run this with qemu, what type of environment would I need? mips64 r2? mips r3000?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an embedded Linux expert however recently I was striving to write a "Hello World" application on my Busybox router. Also, the router had the same processor type (MIPS R3000).

Similar to many embedded devices, the router has an embedded Linux.
Even though it has a different processor and architecture, it's a Linux system that's why It supports the same executable format ELF32/64.

Coming to why you see the machine as "MIPS R3000" and the flag as "mips64r2"
Those indicate the architecture and the specific processor type it has been built for. Different processors might use the same architecture and it's possible to see different flags for the same architecture. However, one thing caught my eye,  R3000 is 32-bit architecture and in my case, the flag was "mips32" so seeing mips64r2(I guess it's 64bit) on 32-bit architecture and 32 bit ELF file is a little bit strange.

You can check out the official MIPS documentation. I hope it helps

[MIPS 64-bit ELF Object File Specification](https://www.linux-mips.org/pub/linux/mips/doc/ABI/elf64-2.4.pdf)

[MIPS SYSTEM V ABI](https://www.linux-mips.org/pub/linux/mips/doc/ABI/psABI_mips3.0.pdf)

[GCC MIPS-Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/MIPS-Options.html)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.